# Selecting rows in csv file by splitting string on specific charater in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to python and I have a csv file that i need to select certain rows based on characters after the third "_".

this is the sample from the csv file:

```
header row
date,ttp_ws_sm_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,117
date,ttp_ws_sm_001_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,31
date,ttp_ws_sm_045_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,145
date,ttp_ws_sm_057_blank, , , , , , , , , , , ,98
date,ttpv1_001_, , , , , , , , , , , ,67
date,ttpv1_001_01, , , , , , , , , , , ,67
...
```

I am trying to select from row[1] where it = 001 and row(13). i cannot seem to figure out how to get this selection working. I have this code:

```
import csv
import sys

source = '\\\\filepath' #the folder i need to pull from
with open(source + '\TTP_13_08.csv') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)

    for row in rows:

       print (row[1], row[13])
```

this prints the two columns for the entire csv file.
 from this csv file I only need the four rows containing 001.

Comment: Aside: if you're using Python 3 as your `print` syntax suggests, you should use `with open(filename, newline='') as f:`, as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> with open(...) as f:
...     rows = csv.reader(f)
...     for row in rows:
...         t = row[1].split('_')
...         if len(t) >= 4 and t[3] == '001':
...             print (row[1], row[13])
... 
('ttp_ws_sm_001_01', '117')
('ttp_ws_sm_001_blank', '31')
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if `001` is in `row[1]`:

```
for row in rows:
    if "001" in row[1]:
        print (row[1], row[13])
```

for your example data, it prints:

```
('ttp_ws_sm_001_01', '117')
('ttp_ws_sm_001_blank', '31')
('ttpv1_001_', '67')
('ttpv1_001_01', '67')
```

Comment: That was the ticket. Thank you for helping. Now off to do more with what i have.

Comment: @MikeHirschmann sure, actually Roman's answer is more precise, consider accepting it, thanks.

Comment: yours is better since the 001 isn't always on the third _. Thanks again

Comment: I followed Roman's code and it works great. Now I am trying to the total or sum of the numbers 117 & 31 from the selection. I was trying this: it comes after the line If len(t)..."001':   for number in range(13):
                 total += int(row[13])
        print ('Club 001' + '\t' + str(total))